# Rails api react and nginx on docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

after setup rails API, react and Nginx

seems that everything is fine but when I try to post or other actions did not go the API! just stay on react!

every tutorial related to this config point the main location to frontend react and secondary location to the backend but as I said before after visit localhost:80 open the react and on any action like the post, put or delete the action did not go to backend.

I've tried to invert location or upstream both locations on the main location and still not understand how to make this work. so please can someone help clarify this?

docker-compose

```
version: "3"
volumes:
  postgres_data: {}

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - frontend
    depends_on:
      - frontend

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=banks_development

  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/frontend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

nginx conf

```
events {

  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {


  server {

    listen 80;


    location /api {

      # proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    }


    # this is where my react-app is located
    location / {

      proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
      proxy_redirect off;
      #proxy_http_version 1.1;
     # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     # proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What URL is the browser application trying to contact?  Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: how do set the communications from the frontend to the backend?

Comment: Hello @DavidMaze, the URL is trying just localhost, yes on console shows signup.jsx:42 POST http://localhost/users 404 (Not Found) and on terminal the nginx shows 

172.23.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2020:20:23:16 +0000] "POST /users HTTP/1.1" 404 145 "http://localhost/signup" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36"

Comment: hello @Al-waleedShihadeh i placed the frontend depends on backend, just that, is something more to do?

Comment: @Al-waleedShihadeh maybe need to add proxy to react package.json like

"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"

Comment: @jjplack the react application need to be able to communicate with the backend application, you need to configure frontend with api url. `http://backend/api`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to configure the frontend with a proxy,same as shown below

```
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1/api"
```

check [this](https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/) for more info

Comment: Hello @Al-waleedShihadeh, thank you for help. that i was missing. i tought that just use proxy if the setup is on the same folder as generally on development is.